# NodeIDAbsentError is thrown when Parent Node clearly exists in Tree(), treelib

Tags: python

Apparently when I import `from treelib import Node, Tree`

And when I test out...

```
from treelib import Node, Tree

my_tree = Tree()

mytree.create_node("theParent")
mytree.create_node("theChild", parent="theParent")
```

I would always get...

```
in add_node
    raise NodeIDAbsentError("Parent node '%s' " "is not in the tree" % pid)
treelib.exceptions.NodeIDAbsentError: Parent node 'theParent' is not in the tree
```

when the parent node is CLEARLY there...

I tried to search for solutions on google, stackoverflow, AI but to no answer.
I find this a rather peculiar problem...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that parent node creation is actually failing due to a missing argument. Try this:
mytree.create_node("theParent", "theParent")